# OpenStreetMap OpenLayers in project require.js

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openstreetmap

I need to connect OpenStreetMap to the project using the OpenLayers library. That's what I have already written. The index file.jsp, in which all the necessary connections are:

```
<%@page import="java.util.Date"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%
String fa = "6.4.2";
String bs = "5.3.1";

    String app_version = "0.0.1";
%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
        
        <!--link rel="icon" href="favicon64.png?name=oemz" type="image/x-icon">
        

        <title>Welcome</title>
    
        <link href="lib/fontawesome/<%= fa%>/css/fontawesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="lib/fontawesome/<%= fa%>/css/brands.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="lib/fontawesome/<%= fa%>/css/solid.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="lib/fontawesome/<%= fa%>/css/regular.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="lib/bootstrap/<%= bs%>/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="lib/osm/ol.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="common/style/main.css?nc=<%= app_version%>" rel="stylesheet">
    
        <script src="lib/requirejs/require-2.3.6.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            "use strict";
    
            require.config({
                // The shim config allows us to configure dependencies for
                // scripts that do not call define() to register a module
                shim: {
                    underscore: {exports: "_"},
                    bootstrap: {deps: ["jquery"]},
                    backbone: {
                        deps: [
                            "underscore",
                            "jquery"
                        ],
                        exports: "Backbone"
                    }
                },
                paths: {
                    jquery: "lib/jquery/jquery-3.7.1.min",
                    underscore: "lib/underscore/underscore-umd-1.13.6.min",
                    backbone: "lib/backbone/backbone-1.5.0.min",
                    bootstrap: "lib/bootstrap/5.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min",
                    text: "lib/requirejs/text-2.0.16.min",
                    ol: "lib/osm/ol",
    
                    modules: "app/modules"
                },
                urlArgs: function (id, url) {
                    var nc = "nc=<%= app_version%>";
                    ;
                    if (url.indexOf("./lib/") !== -1) {
                        nc = "";
                    }
    
                    return nc == "" ? "" : ((url.indexOf("?") === -1 ? "?" : "&") + nc);
                }
            });
    
            require(["jquery", "backbone", "app/router", "app/app"],
                    function ($, Backbone, Router, App) {
                        new App({el: "body"}).render();
    
                        new Router({$container: $("main")});
                        Backbone.history.start();
                    });
        </script>
    </body>
```

map-view.html:

```
<h1>Карта</h1>
<div id="mapContainer" class = "p-5 mb-4 bg-body-tertiary rounded-3"></div>
```

map-view.js:

```
define(["jquery", "backbone", "text!modules/map/map-view.html", "bootstrap", "ol"],
function ($, Backbone, html, ol) {
"use strict";
let Clazz = Backbone.View.extend({
$container: null,
initialize: function (p) {
p = p || {};
this.$container = p.$container || this.$container;
},
render: function () {
this.$el.html(html);
this.initMap();
return this;
},

                initMap: function () {
                    var map = new ol.Map({
                        target: 'mapContainer', 
                        layers: [
                            // Загружаем тайловый слой
                            new ol.Tile({
                                source: new ol.OSM()
                            })
                        ],
                        view: new ol.View({
                            center: [32, 113], 
                            zoom: 2 
                        })
                    });
                },
                load: function () {
                    let defer = $.Deferred();
                    this.render();
                    this.$container.html(this.$el);
                    defer.resolve();
                    return defer.promise();
                },
                clear: function () {
                    this.remove();
                }
            });
            return Clazz;
        });
```

ol.css, ol.js and ol.js.map are taken from here https://openlayers.org/download/

At startup, the map does not appear on the page, and in the console there is such an error:

```
map-view.js?nc=0.0.1:26 Uncaught TypeError: ol.OSM is not a constructor     at r.initMap (map-view.js?nc=0.0.1:26:17)     at r.render (map-view.js?nc=0.0.1:13:11)     at r.load (map-view.js?nc=0.0.1:133:11)     at router.js?nc=0.0.1:47:18     at Object.execCb (require-2.3.6.min.js:5:16727)     at e.check (require-2.3.6.min.js:5:10499)     at e.\<anonymous\> (require-2.3.6.min.js:5:12915)     at require-2.3.6.min.js:5:1542     at require-2.3.6.min.js:5:13376     at each (require-2.3.6.min.js:5:1020)
```

Instead of ol.OSM, I tried ol.source.OSM, then another error

```
map-view.js?nc=0.0.1:26 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'OSM')     at r.initMap (map-view.js?nc=0.0.1:26:31)     at r.render (map-view.js?nc=0.0.1:13:11)     at r.load (map-view.js?nc=0.0.1:133:11)     at router.js?nc=0.0.1:47:18     at Object.execCb (require-2.3.6.min.js:5:16727)     at e.check (require-2.3.6.min.js:5:10499)     at e.\<anonymous\> (require-2.3.6.min.js:5:12915)     at require-2.3.6.min.js:5:1542     at require-2.3.6.min.js:5:13376     at each (require-2.3.6.min.js:5:1020)
```

Please tell me how to connect the library correctly and why it gives such errors.

Comment: Hi, did you check this link?: https://openlayers.org/doc/quickstart.html

Comment: Of course! The problem is that I have a project without node.js

Comment: OSM is a Source: import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM.js';

Comment: Syntax with full build is the same as in old version examples https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/examples/simple.html

Comment: map-view.js?nc=0.0.1:18 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Map')
    at r.initMap (map-view.js?nc=0.0.1:18:23)
    at r.render (map-view.js?nc=0.0.1:13:11)
    at r.load (map-view.js?nc=0.0.1:154:11)
    at router.js?nc=0.0.1:47:18
    at Object.execCb (require-2.3.6.min.js:5:16727)
    at e.check (require-2.3.6.min.js:5:10499)
    at e.<anonymous> (require-2.3.6.min.js:5:12915)
    at require-2.3.6.min.js:5:1542
    at require-2.3.6.min.js:5:13376
    at each (require-2.3.6.min.js:5:1020)